# Feed iframe elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have found many questions here regarding iframes and jquery and have tried the solutions for them without success. Here is my iframe setup and the jquery I have tried.

**html:**

```
<iframe id="jiraFrame"height="700" width="1000" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#jiraFrame').load(function(){
     $('#jiraFrame').contents().find('body').html('Hey, Ive changed!');
});
```

*also tried*

```
var $currentFrame = $('#jiraFrame');
$currentFrame.contents().find("body #summary").val('customer');
```

I have tried multiple src sites in the iframe and the summary id exists for sure in the source from the frame. Maybe I am just missing something simple but I can't see it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First iframes rule: http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Comment: like above : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are probably missing error messages such as

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'

This is Cross-Origin policy, forbidding you to access (and manipulate) the content of iframe from other domain, except `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers are set.

If you are running apache, the easiest way to work around is to use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) in httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass /example_com/ http://example.com/
```

```html
<iframe id="jiraFrame"height="700" width="1000" src="/example_com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Web Devie! I do see an error that I hadn't noticed before. It says `Error: Permission denied to access property 'jQuery'`. I tried to set up ProxyPass in my httpd file but still don't have success posting any of the jquery generated data. Is the `jquery` error a seperate issue than a `nodeType`?

Comment: Would the `jquery` error be resolved the same as a `nodeType` error?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but I had this same error with our CKEditor installation. It turns out it was a combination of JQuery 1.3 (it's ultra old, but we're currently unable to update it as it is too messily hard-coded (yay for inheriting code!)), and Firefox.

Hard-refreshing the page worked perfectly. :)